# log4j not writing logs

Tags: java, log4j, qpid

Below is my log4j configuration

> ```
> #log4j.additivity.org.apache.qpid=false
>
> log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console
> log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.console.threshold=DEBUG
> log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.javax.jms=DEBUG
> log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid=DEBUG
> log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0=DEBUG
> log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms=DEBUG
> ```

and then in code

```
    String log4jConfigFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfigFile);
    logger.debug("this is a debug log message");
```

my debug message `this is a debug log message` do get printed but the log messages from `org.apache.qpid` are not getting printed on console

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms</artifactId>
        <version>0.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT**
I am a newbie in java... The logging dependencies I have added. Do I need add some setting somewhere to redirect sl4j logs to log4j??

```
    <slf4j-version>1.6.6</slf4j-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am quite sure that apache org.apache.qpid use slf4j for logging, have you setup the __slf4j binder__ to use log4j as implementation ? Have you tried to add the for exampes the log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar jar ?

Comment: @gtosto added the details you needed as edit.. also I am newbie to java, do I need some other config setting somewhere to redirect sl4j to log4j

Comment: if you can: I suggest you to use a more recent version of the qpid amqp client that relies on the slf4j. Otherwise like stated by @rob-godfrey you have to configure the built-in java logging framework. See his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The (deprecated) `qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms` client used `java.util.logging`, and not log4j.  To quote from a [mail](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/qpid-users/201402.mbox/%3CCACsaS94QyZbYrScWNtChgk=Gn3oJDzgSL5sk5rrNVoJ9iZj7Eg@mail.gmail.com%3E) I sent back in 2014 to the users@qpid.apache.org mailing list:

> you can turn it on by setting the Java system property
>   `java.util.logging.config.file` to point to a file that looks something
>   like this:
>
> ```
> handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler FRM.level=ALL
> java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
> java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tc] %4$s: %5$s%n
>
> java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL`
>
> # (The output file is placed in the directory
> # defined by the "user.home" System property.) 
> java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/qpid-jms-%u.log`
> ```
>
> When you run the client it should then generate a file called
>   qpid-jms-0.log in your home directory, with output that looks
>   something like:
>
> ```
> [Mon Feb 24 18:45:58 CET 2014] FINE: RECV[/127.0.0.1:5672|0] :
> SaslMechanisms{saslServerMechanisms=[ANONYMOUS]}
> ```

Note that the logging in this old client is really very minimal and ideally you should instead migrate your code to the supported Qpid JMS client for AMQP 1.0 https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html which does use slf4j, but uses different configuration syntax for connections and queues.